# Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' in AZURE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I created an ASP.Net MVC site using Entity Framework. The site is works fine on both IIS and IIS Express.

But when I upload it on an Azure Web App then I get following error:

> Attempt by security transparent method
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()'
>   to access security critical method
>   'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly,
>   System.String)' failed.

Here's how I am publishing the site. I right click on my solution in Visual Studio and click "Publish". Then I chose "File System" and it publishes the complete site in C:\MySite. After that I upload it on Azure using FTP.

One of the solution I saw on Stackoverflow is to define following code in assemblyinfo.cs which I have already done but no luck.

```
[assembly: System.Security.SecurityTransparent()]
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting "System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll" file from Azure bin folder fixed the issue.